# I need help, my java program is returning nothing when i compile it

Tags: java, class, loops

I'm a college student doing a Java homework. I've created this program that allows user to enter a job information.

The problem is that my program doesn't return information entered.

I look at my program for a while, but I know it's something simple I'm missing.

```
public class Employee 
{
    String name;             // Employee name
    String employeeNumber;   // Employee number
    String hireDate;         // Employee hire date
    int shift;                   // Employee shift
    double payRate; 

    public void setEmployeeNumber(String e)
    {
       if (isValidEmpNum(e))
       {
          employeeNumber = e;
       }
       else
       {
          employeeNumber = "";
       }
    }

    public Employee(String name, String e, String hireDate, double payRate, int shift)
    {
       this.name = name;
       this.setEmployeeNumber(e);
       this.hireDate = hireDate;
       this.payRate = payRate;
       this.shift = shift; 
    }

    public Employee()
    {
       name = "";
       employeeNumber = "";
       hireDate = "";
    }

    public void setpayRate(double payRate)
    {
       this.payRate = payRate;
    }

    public double getpayRate()
    {
       return payRate;
    }

    public void setshift(int shift)
    {
       this.shift = shift;
    }

    public int getshift()
    {
       return shift;
    }


    public void setName(String name)
    {
       this.name = name;
    }

    public void setHireDate(String hireDate)
    {
       this.hireDate = hireDate;
    }

        public String getName()
    {
       return name;
    }

    public String getEmployeeNumber()
    {
       return employeeNumber;
    }

    public String getHireDate()
    {
       return hireDate;
    }

    private boolean isValidEmpNum(String e)
    {
       boolean status = true;

       if (e.length() != 5)
          status = false;
       else
       {
         if ((!Character.isDigit(e.charAt(0)))  ||
            (!Character.isDigit(e.charAt(1)))   ||
            (!Character.isDigit(e.charAt(2)))   ||
            (e.charAt(3) != '-')                ||
            (!Character.isLetter(e.charAt(4)))  ||
            (!(e.charAt(4)>= 'A' && e.charAt(4)<= 'M')))
          {
             status = false;
          }
       }
       return status;
    }
    public String toString()
    {
       String str = "Name: " + name + "\nEmployee Number: ";

       if (employeeNumber == "")
       {
          str += "INVALID EMPLOYEE NUMBER";
       }
       else
       {
          str += employeeNumber;
       }

       str += ("\nHire Date: " + hireDate);
       return str;
    }  
}
```

I declared this in another class.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ProductionWorkerDemo extends Employee 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       String name;             // Employee name
       String employeeNumber;   // Employee number
       String hireDate;         // Employee hire date
       int shift;                    // Employee shift
       double payRate;               // Employee pay
       String str;
       String str2;


       name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your name: ");

       employeeNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your employee number: ");

       hireDate = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your hire date: ");

       str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your shift: ");

       payRate = Double.parseDouble(str);

       str2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your payrate: ");

       payRate = Double.parseDouble(str2);

       ProductionWorkerDemo pw = new ProductionWorkerDemo();

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Name: " + pw.getName());
        System.out.println("Employee Number: " + pw.getEmployeeNumber());
        System.out.println("Hire Date: " + pw.getHireDate());
        System.out.println("Pay Rate: " + pw.getpayRate());
        System.out.println("Shift: " + pw.getshift());

    }
}
```

Comment: Unreadable format mishap, I can't help until someone fixes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the employee information on local variables only. You are not passing them to the ProductionWorkerDemo nor it's super class Employee.

1. You don't need to extend the Employee with the ProductionWorkerDemo as the ProductionWorkerDemo is not an Employee. You can just remove the extends Employee text.
2. You're not passing the variables to the Employee. You've created a constructor in the Employee class that takes them all so you can use it

   `Employee pw = new Employee(name, employeeNumber, hireRate, payRate, shift);`
3. Now you'll notice that you haven't asked for the shift.

Comment: Aleksi what do you mean i'm not asking for shift?

Comment: You have a dialog asking for shift but you assign it to the payrate variable instead.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use an appropiate constructor or the `set*` methods to set the fields on the object. Currently, all of them are empty, thus the `get*` methods return either nothing or default values.

Also, you shouldn't extend `Employee` with the class containing the main method, just use the `Employee` class directly (the idea behind inherting from a class is to extend it, in your case you just need it as an object so save data, so don't derive from it but use it):

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ProductionWorkerDemo
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       String name;             // Employee name
       String employeeNumber;   // Employee number
       String hireDate;         // Employee hire date
       int shift;                    // Employee shift
       double payRate;               // Employee pay
       String str;
       String str2;


       name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your name: ");

       employeeNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your employee number: ");

       hireDate = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your hire date: ");

       str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your shift: ");

       payRate = Double.parseDouble(str);

       str2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your payrate: ");

       payRate = Double.parseDouble(str2);

       Employee pw = new Employee(/*provide arguments here*/);

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Name: " + pw.getName());
        System.out.println("Employee Number: " + pw.getEmployeeNumber());
        System.out.println("Hire Date: " + pw.getHireDate());
        System.out.println("Pay Rate: " + pw.getpayRate());
        System.out.println("Shift: " + pw.getshift());

    }
}
```

Comment: Is my set and get methods wrong in the Employee class. Or do i need them in ProductionWorkerDemo class

Comment: It's not that it's wrong being there. because they're in employee, and they're public, you have them in productionworkerdemo as well. The problem is you're not using them.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to add the constructor you the Demo Class:

```
public class ProductionWorkerDemo extends Employee{

  public ProductionWorkerDemo(String name, String e, String hireDate, double payRate, nt shift){
 {
     super(name, e, hireDate, payRate, shift);
  }

}
```

Then in your class you need to instantiate:

```
ProductionWorkerDemo pw = new ProductionWorkerDemo(name, 
                                    employeeNumber, 
                                    hireDate,
                                    payRate,
                                    shift);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring variables called name, employeenumber, etc in your main method. When you try to use them, it's going to use those, not your class variables.

why don't you try making a new ProductionWorkerDemo based on the constructor you defined in Employee class?

```
ProductionWorkerDemo pw = new ProductionWorkerDemo(name,employeeNumber,hireDate,payRate,shift);
```

And also, your payRate is being assigned twice, you should change the first one to shift, and use Integer.parseInt

Answer (score 0):

You have local variables in `main()` whose values you are setting. You then create a `ProductionWorkerDemo` object, who has instance variables with the same names, but are all initially empty, due to the constructor setting them that way.

You never pass your local variables in to your `ProductionWorkerDemo` object, so when you call the getters they return the empty values.

Answer (score 0):

I fix the problem with my program, thanks for the help everyone.

I was not passing the variables to the Employee.

I add this statement to ProductionWorkerDemo class.

Employee pw = new Employee(name, employeeNumber, hireRate, payRate, shift);

P.S. You can close this thread.